# match id of one table to user_id of another table to fetch records in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have two tables,lets say x and y. i am using two queries to fetch x table data by one query and fetch all rows from y table  matching x's  id with y's UserId

here is my mysql

include 'config.php';

```
$sql1= mysql_query("select FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Location,Email,Mobile from personaldetails limit 1");

$sql2 = mysql_query("select BookTilte,BookGenre,BookWriter,BookDescription from bookdetails where personaldetails.Id = bookdetails.UserId ")
```

Please also suggest some alternative solution if it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can use from INNER JOIN in these cases

```
SELECT FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Location,Email,Mobile,BookTilte,BookGenre,BookWriter,BookDescription FROM `personaldetails` as `PD` INNER JOIN `bookdetails` AS `BD` ON `PD`.`Id` = `BD`.`UserId`
```

Note: mysql_query is deprecated and you should use mysqli functions

Comment: Yes,it's one way but i would like to store both table data into different varialbes or arrays so i can display it simply by using api

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query

```
$sql1= mysql_query("select a.FirstName,a.MiddleName,a.LastName,a.Gender,a.Location,a.Email,a.Mobile,b.BookTilte,b.BookGenre,b.BookWriter,b.BookDescription from personaldetails as a join bookdetails as b on a.Id=b.UserId  limit 1");
```

> **Join** will combine the two tables.
>
> **a** and **b** are aliases of two tables. By using aliases, we can specify
>   which field select from which table.
>
> **a.Id=b.UserId** is for specify the primary key and reference key

Comment: is there any way i can store both tables rows in different variables by matching id?

Answer (score 0):

It s not wrong, it could be the right thing to do sometimes.

An alternative solution could be

```
$str = <<<MARKER
SELECT FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Gender,Location,Email,Mobile 
FROM personaldetails 
INNER JOIN bookdetails ON (personaldetails.Id = bookdetails.UserId)
ORDER BY personaldetails.Id
MARKER;
$sql1= mysql_query($query);
```

Notes,

- you don't need the limit anymore as it would return only the first row.
- For each `bookdetails`, you ll find a `personaldetails` line (`personaldetails` will be duplicated),
- I added an `ORDER BY` clause to show you.
- you should reference primary keys, or indexed columns, or add new indexes